# Update database with range of values

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that filter data range by ID. That is I'm giving option to enter from Id and to Id and filter data. Now I want to update two columns to those filtered data. Can some one tell me how to do that. I want to update using a button click.

This is my query to filter data:

```
SELECT * FROM pass WHERE pass_id BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
```

I have tried to update data from following query:

```
UPDATE pass SET  cash_s_date = '$date', cash_status = '$cstatus'
WHERE pass_id BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'
```

but it doesn't work,

Comment: are you facing any error? Did you get any records in `select` query?

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should address imminently

Comment: A very basic porblem is your escaping. I would recommend to wrap the query itself with double quotes and the values exclude from the query like this: `SELECT * FROM pass WHERE pass_id BETWEEN '" . htmlspecialchars($start) . "' AND '" . htmlspecialchars($end) . "'`

Comment: @unherz `htmlspecialchars()` shouldn't be used to escape SQL data. It's for displaying data on web pages in order to prevent XSS.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL-Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostGres?

Comment: Try this `UPDATE pass SET  cash_s_date = '$date', cash_status = '$cstatus'
WHERE pass_id >= '$start' AND  pass_id <=  '$end'`

Comment: @M.Hemant I didn't get any errors. yes in select query i got records

Comment: @Barmer  I'm using phpmyadmin on wampserver that i already hosted

Comment: @Barmar sure its not safe but that wasnt the point here. It was jsut to demonstrate where he should improve the security of his query. For sure you have to escape all special chars to be parsed as string and also its better to use PDO!

Comment: Just give them a link to [how can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) rather than giving them bad advice.

Comment: @ZainFarooq that you. It works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use greater than and less than option here

```
UPDATE pass SET cash_s_date = '$date', cash_status = '$cstatus' WHERE pass_id >= '$start' AND pass_id <= '$end';
```

However I suggest you to use [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to prevent sql injections as your this query is open to [sql injections](https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/)